# Generate OpenApi 3 from ApiControllers (C#, .Net 4.5)

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, openapi, nswag, openapi-generator

We are using Swashbuckle to generate a swagger 2.0 json, using C# on Asp .Net 4.5 (not Asp .Net core). I am trying to adapt our solution to generate openApi 3.0:

- I understand that Swashbuckle for .Net 4.5 currently does not support openApi 3.0
- I tried using nSwag, but it seems that the openApi that is generated is always 2.0, regardless of using the function UseSwaggerUi3, or using GenerateForControllersAsync with SchemaType = SchemaType.OpenApi3.

Is it supported in nSwag for .Net 4.5? If not, is there any other tool or solution without upgrading to .Net core?

The code I tried with nSwag:

```
var settings = new WebApiToSwaggerGeneratorSettings
        {
            DefaultUrlTemplate = "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        };

        var jsonSettings = new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings();
        jsonSettings.SchemaType = SchemaType.OpenApi3;
        var schemaGen = new SwaggerJsonSchemaGenerator(jsonSettings);
        var generator = new WebApiToSwaggerGenerator(settings, schemaGen);
        var document = Task.Run(async () => await generator.GenerateForControllersAsync(controllers))
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var x= document.ToJson();
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me and should work. Are you sing the latestversion of nswag?

Comment: Yes, but the generated version was still openApi 2. I found the list of currently implemented features for NSwag, and it seems that the swagger generators are not implemented yet - https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/issues/945

Comment: We use internal conversions between the models so it should already work. Are you using the letest version?

Comment: I had to switch to a different task. Eventually we used Microsoft.OpenApi package to convert the generated spec